# vSphere client cant connect after restart

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Today all servers lost external connections simultaneously, we were unable to RDP or SSH to any of the servers with an external connection, however we could still access the ESXI server with vSphere client at IP XXX.XXX.XX.46 and access each of the individual servers using the vSphere console.

Each of the servers were able to ping each other internally, but were unable to ping each other or other sources externally, after exhausting troubleshooting steps we found an article online mentioning a similar issue with ESXI and suggested in the ESXI OS changing the IP address from static to DHCP and then back to static.

So I accessed the ESXI server OS through IPMI and did so, and now we can no longer access the ESXI server with vSphere client at IP XXX.XXX.XX.46, we still have IMPI access through the VPN

As it stands our entire solution is currently offline, and has been offline for 4 hours, your urgent response and any assistance you can provide is appreciated

Comment: Your problem can be caused by vlan configuration. Can you check your network configuration again?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to ESXi DCUI(direct access to hosts)?
You can configure management network in console, like described [here](http://blogs.vmware.com/smb/2013/12/back-to-basics-managing-vmware-esxi-5-5-direct-user-interface-dcui.html)